# Why is this NLog layout's "when" clause not working?

Tags: logging, nlog

I have an NLog layout like this:

```
${date} ${uppercase:${level}} ${when:when=(level)>=LogLevel.Debug:callsite:includeSourcePath=false}: ${message}
```

The `when` mostly works. My log entries don't show the call site, because they are at `Info` level, but the word `callsite` is output in the log entry as a literal:

> 2016/10/06 09:15:15.814 INFO **callsite**: Application has started
>   monitoring 'MSSQLSERVER' service at 10 second intervals.

If I try the layout like this:

```
${date} ${uppercase:${level}} ${when:when=(level)>=LogLevel.Debug:${callsite:includeSourcePath=false}}: ${message}
```

then the `when` doesn't work at all, and the entries include correctly outpout call site info:

> 2016/10/06 09:17:01.718 INFO
>   SqlServer.Monitor.Application.MonitorApplication.Start: Application
>   has started monitoring 'MSSQLSERVER' service at 10 second intervals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the specs this should work:

```
${date} ${uppercase:${level}} ${when:when=(level>=LogLevel.Debug):inner=${callsite:includeSourcePath=false}}: ${message}
```

Update, you where missing the `:inner`. This is required as the first parameter of `{when}` in this case is `when=`.

Another example which is working:

```
${when:when=level<=LogLevel.Info:inner=Good:else=Bad}
```

See the tests in [this PR on GitHub](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/pull/1687)

Comment: I have added the example to the docs: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/When-Layout-Renderer